# Uso de uma função void _dolarChanged(String text) gerando mensagem de erro no onChanged

Tags: flutter, dart

Criei a seguinte função:

```
void _dolarChanged(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      _clearAll();
      return;
    }

    final double dolar = double.parse(text);
    realController.text = (dolar * this.dolar).toStringAsFixed(2);
    euroController.text = (dolar * this.dolar / euro).toStringAsFixed(2);
}
```

Para ser utilizado em um `TextField` no `onChanged` dentro de um Widget, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)'

A chamada do Widget:

```
buildTextField('Dolares', 'US\$ ', dolarController, _dolarChanged),
```

```
Widget buildTextField(
  String label,
  String prefix,
  TextEditingController controller,
  Function function,
) {
  return TextField(
    controller: controller,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      prefixText: prefix,
    ),
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.amber,
      fontSize: 25,
    ),
    onChanged: function,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  );
}
```

Alguém já passou por este erro ou sabe como posso corrigi-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O parâmetro `onChanged` do `TextField` espera um objeto do tipo `ValueChanged<String>`.

Sendo este um *typedef* definido como:

```dart
typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);
```

Então altere seu método para receber um `Function(String)`:

```dart
Widget buildTextField(
  String label,
  String prefix,
  TextEditingController controller,
  Function(String) function,
) {
  return TextField(
    controller: controller,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      prefixText: prefix,
    ),
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.amber,
      fontSize: 25,
    ),
    onChanged: function,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  );
}
```

O que é exatamente o que a mensagem de erro informa:

`The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)'.`

Answer (score 1):

Você tem duas alternativas:

- Pode definir a sua função especificando o tipo do parâmetro e do retorno, da seguinte forma:

```
[...]
  TextEditingController controller,
  void Function (String) function,
) {
[...]
```

- Chamar a função manualmente onde ela é necessária internamente:

```
[...]
onChanged: (String a)=>function(a),
[...]
```

Esse erro ocorre porque apenas `Function` é menos restrito do que uma `Function` que aceita uma `string` de retorno `void`. Para proteger o programador, este erro é disparado.